# Convert Rails Codeblocks to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a Ruby on Rails App that uses an HTML5 view (with JQuery Mobile) to interact with a user.  It's currently deployed to Heroku.

I'd like to wrap the view up in PhoneGap so I can submit it to the Apple App Store.

Does anyone know of a tutorial or a resource to help me convert the Ruby code blocks and helpers I have in the HTML5 View to JavaScript language, so it will play well with PhoneGap?  PhoneGap only accepts HTML, JavaScript, and CSS.

Here's some sample code I'd like to move out of Ruby code block and into JS.  Thanks!

```
        <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-content-theme="d">
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h3>See Previous Tips</h3>
            <ul data-role="listview">                       
                <% @past_tips.each do |tip| %>
                    <li>
                        <h3><%= tip.outboundtitle %></h3><!-- page one title -->
                        <p><%= tip.outboundlittle %></p><!-- page one subtitle -->
                            <ul><!-- Second page with full tip -->
                                <li><p><%= tip.outgoing %></p>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>               
                <% end %>               
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but only the Apple App Store? :).

Comment: There's no direct "mechanical" way to transform the pages as they're currently written. It all depends on exactly how your particular application works, but basically you're going to have to start using some JavaScript template engine and use that with whatever data your Ruby code provides, but transformed into JSON from your application server, or something like that. Basically, you're re-writing your application front end.

Comment: Thank you Pointy!  Do you want to make this an 'answer' so I can accept it?